# Unable to make Indian E-visa payment

Tags: visas, india

When I am applying for a 30 day tourist E-visa, on the official Indian visa site (https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/), I keep getting stuck at the payment part. It says:

> The Visa fee payment status updation may take up to 2 hours due to technical reasons/network delays.
>
> Applicants are advised to wait for 2 hours before payment of Visa fee again. In cases, where Visa fee has been deducted but status is not updated, the applicants are advised to verify their payment status by clicking on 'Verify Payment/Pay Visa Fee' tab on Home page.

No matter how long I wait, I keep getting the same error.
Does anybody know what I can do to make it work?

I'm from the Netherlands myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try again after few Hours, if the problem still occurs, call the helpline or check with your bank from which you're paying. Also check the cache memory of the PC or the device you're using. Clear the cache memory and check again

Comment: Or change provider for payment (indian side and your credit card). I recommend to print your application, you may do to it again. It happened also to me. Second time, changing providers helped.

Comment: I had the same problem and I only had to wait some time and try again. The system is bugged for some time now.

Answer (score 3):

On another blog I found that using AXis bank payment portal would be better than using SBI portal. However, my card (both mastercard and visa) got declined on both SBI and axis payment pages.

I was able to successfully make the payment by using my Paypal balance. Mind it that Paypal balance requires 3-5 days for update through US bank accounts. I had to call a friend to send me money on PayPal for instant transfer. I did not wanted to use the pay by credit card option through Paypal as I was too scared if my payment gets rejected this time, I will have to fill the form again.